# Google analytics not showing anything and no error

Tags: google-analytics, embed, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use `google analytics` data in my web page. I added the code like describing [Here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/).

But it is not showing anything. I added a console code after inside

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
```

That is also not showing. The client ID I am using is a demo one which I created for testing purpose.

What may be the wrong thing I am doing? Please help. I am new to this analytics data.

Answer (score 0):

That loks like incomplete code to me, when you set up the tracking code you should have a script like this.

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()  {(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=gm.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Then copy paste it to the footer of you website.

Note the code above wont work with copy paste. Make sure your getting your tracking code from here. https://analytics.google.com

Comment: The question is not related to tracking. It is related to API.

Comment: @dikesh, Yeah. It is related to API only. Not tracking. You have any clue?

Comment: It's hard to tell as you haven't provided much code, but it looks like your trying to implement this. So follow this guide instead. 
[link]https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started[link]